# Docker Compose Volume Not Updating on Image Change

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm facing an issue with Docker Compose where the contents of a volume are not updating when the image is changed. Here's a simplified version of my ***docker-compose.yml:***

```
services:
  app:
    image: docker/image:66
    # ... other configurations ...
    volumes:
      - app:/var/www/html
    # ... other configurations ...

  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    # ... other configurations ...
    volumes:
      - app:/var/www/html
    # ... other configurations ...

volumes:
  app:
```

The problem arises when I change the docker/image:66 to a different version, and then run docker-compose up -d. The contents of the volume (app:/var/www/html) do not reflect the changes from the new image.

I understand that volumes are cached, and stopping containers and manually deleting the image resolves the issue. However, I believe there should be a more efficient way to handle this without manual intervention.

I've tried separating volumes for each service and using named volumes with an external driver, but the issue persists. Is there a recommended approach to ensure that the volume updates automatically when the image is changed without the need for manual steps?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: U can't mount a volume on /var/www/html. You've got three options either create a symbolic link or use a bind-mount, or reconfigure the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `volumes:` entirely.

The `volumes:` mount always replaces the content of the image with the contents of the named volume.  Nothing is ever copied into the named volume, except for one corner case at first use.  As you're seeing here, volumes are not a reliable path to share content from one container to another.

In your proxy container, I'd recommend building a separate image with whatever static assets you need to serve built in.  Easiest is if you can delegate static-file serving to the application container, so you might need an Nginx configuration with a `proxy_pass` line but no application-specific files at all.  If your application framework doesn't support static file serving then you can build a straightforward image

```bash
FROM nginx
ARG app_image=docker/image
COPY --from=${app_image} /var/www/html/ /var/www/html/
```

In the Compose file you can use variable substitution to avoid repeating the image tag.  If both containers have the same tag then you can say

```yaml
services:
  app:
    image: docker/image:${IMAGE_TAG:-latest}
 webserver:
    # if your CI system builds both images
    image: docker/proxy:${IMAGE_TAG:-latest}
    # if you need to build it yourself
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        app_image: docker/image:${IMAGE_TAG:-latest}
```