# Docker-Compose is not updating files even if i chose --no-cache

Tags: docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

my project looks like this.
I'm using AWS for deploy.

```
server
 ┣ nginx
 ┃ ┗ nginx.conf
 ┣ server
 ┃ ┣ accounts
 ┃ ┣ appserver
 ┃ ┣ db.sqlite3
 ┃ ┗ manage.py
 ┣ Dockerfile
 ┗ docker-compose.yml
```

in appserver/settings
there are base.py, deploy.py, dev.py
deploy.py looks like this

```
from .base import *

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'appserver.wsgi.deploy.application'

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://-', 'https://-']

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

my docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.17.10
        container_name: ng01
        volumes:
            - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - tmp:/tmp/
            - server:/server/
        depends_on:
            - server
        networks:
            - my_network
        ports:
            - "80:80"

    server:
        build: .
        container_name: dg01
        command: bash -c "
            python3 manage.py makemigrations &&
            python3 manage.py migrate &&
            python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input && 
            gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock appserver.wsgi.deploy:application"
        volumes:
            - server:/server/
            - tmp:/tmp/
        networks:
            - my_network

networks:
    my_network:

volumes:
    tmp:
    server:
```

and my dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

RUN pip install django
RUN pip install djangorestframework
RUN pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt
RUN pip install gunicorn
RUN pip install requests

RUN mkdir /server

COPY server/ server/

WORKDIR /server/

EXPOSE 80
```

since I'm having CSRF 403 Forbidden problem, I'm trying to change DEBUG = True.
So I dit it by vi editor in aws.

```
from .base import *

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'appserver.wsgi.deploy.application'

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://-', 'https://-']

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

But Even If I do
docker system prune -af
and rebuild by docker-compose up, it never changes to DEBUG=True

I've expected DEBUG = True but it always shows 'Change DEBUG=True to see the error msg.'
ps. I'm Also curious why it shows CSRF Fail only on django-admin

Comment: This sounds exactly the same as [Docker Compose Volume Not Updating on Image Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77703367/docker-compose-volume-not-updating-on-image-change), and the most important thing is to delete the `volumes:` that hide the image code.  My answer to that question also discusses how to get static assets into an Nginx-based reverse proxy.

Comment: Yeah but as I know, "docker system prune -af" includes deleting all volumes too. Isn't it right?

Comment: Also I'm using docker volume to share tmp/gunicorn.sock. Is there another way without using gunicorn.sock?

Comment: Configure GUnicorn to use an HTTP listener, and use the Compose service name `server` in your Nginx `proxy_pass` directive.

Comment: Oh.. Is there no way to do with gunicorn socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved by not using docker volume as David mentioned
but still using it for gunicorn.sock, and works fine.

```
server
 ┣ nginx
 ┃ ┗ nginx.conf
 ┃ ┗ DockerFile
 ┣ server
 ┃ ┣ accounts
 ┃ ┣ appserver
 ┃ ┣ db.sqlite3
 ┃ ┣ DockerFile
 ┃ ┗ manage.py
 ┗ docker-compose.yml
```

This is a docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    nginx:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: nginx/Dockerfile
        container_name: ng01
        volumes:
            - tmp:/tmp/
        # 'server' 컨테이너가 구동된 후 실행된다
        depends_on:
            - server
        networks:
            - my_network
        ports:
            - "80:80"

    server:
        build: ./server/.
        container_name: dg01
        command: bash -c "
            python3 manage.py migrate &&
            gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock appserver.wsgi.deploy:application"
        volumes:
            - tmp:/tmp/
        networks:
            - my_network

networks:
    my_network:

volumes:
    tmp:`
    enter code here
```

DockerFile of NGINX

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN mkdir /static
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY server/appserver/static/ static/

EXPOSE 80
```

DockerFile of Server

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

RUN pip install django
RUN pip install djangorestframework
RUN pip install djangorestframework-simplejwt
RUN pip install gunicorn
RUN pip install requests

RUN mkdir /server

COPY . server/

WORKDIR /server/

EXPOSE 80
```